# ASP.NET web app slow response after a pause

Tags: asp.net, hosting, sql-server-ce, performance

I'm building a web app using ASP.NET MVC and MS SQL Server CE and deploying it to a shared hosting. Every time I approaching my site after a pause (half an hour) it performs very slow. It takes about 40 seconds to load the first page. After this every page opens quickly. 
Please advice what may cause the problem and how to solve it.
Thanks

**Update:** It appeared that after a pause in visiting (10-20 min) the site is loaded from the server hard drive not memory. That is why it was so slow. Possible solutions are increase site visits, move to a virtual server or ping the home page regulary. 
My hosting provider has an option for pinging besides some solutions are described here [c# ping a website? (keep-alive service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226060/c-sharp-ping-a-website-keep-alive-service)

Comment: Do you happen to do anything time consuming on Application Start (in global.asax)

Comment: @Stilgar No, global.asax includes only a number of routes.MapRoute

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a local IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If the worker process is not processing requests it will shut down the worker process after the specified number of minutes. (if configured)

Not sure what version of IIS you are using but look into "Idle Time-out (minutes)". IIS 7 specific info below...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As a paliative, set your app to recycle only after a long period of inactivity.

See [Configure an Application Pool to Recycle at a Scheduled Time (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I believe he can't do this in a shared hosting.

Comment: I believe you are correct in most cases.  Discountasp.net allows you to attach the Microsoft IIS Manager, so I assume you can do it from there, but I may be wrong.