# .Net web app Performance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, iis-6

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app using IIS 6 on windows server 2003.

We are experiencing some performance issues.  Mainly on the initial load of a page.

I have compiled the app into Release mode and the performance is way better than in Debug.  But, still the first load of a page is slow and also if the page lies dormant for a period of time, and the user re-engages the app, the page loads slowly again.  It seems to me that there is runtime compiling going and that, once compiled, objects time out after a period.

What can I do to speed up the initial page loads and the extended dormant page loads?

Is there a way to simulate and load a page automatically at some interval?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean IIS 7? IIS 6 comes on Windows 2003.

Comment: It's IIS 6 BUILD 6002 Service Pack 2.  Not sure why the server is configured like that.  Unfortunately it's not my box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are experiencing the loading and unloading of the Application Pool in IIS.  Think of your web application like any desktop application on your computer.  It takes time to actually open the program, but once open -> actions within the program run quickly.  So, the first time you hit your web application, IIS is starting up the application inside of the App Pool.

The second item you are seeing is IIS unloading the app pool after a period of inactivity (default 20 minutes).  After the default period, the app pool in unloaded.  When a request comes in to your application, IIS again has to start up the application before it can serve the request.

As for when a user first hits the web application, there is nothing you can really do to speed this up, it happens.  Anytime you change your web.config or alter items in the Bin folder, IIS will recycle the app pool.

For the idle timeout concern, you can adjust how long IIS waits until it unloads the app pool (up to a maximum of 29 hours I believe).

[IIS 6 - App Pool Timeout Change](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83b35271-c93c-49f4-b923-7fdca6fae1cf.mspx?mfr=true)

[[IIS 7 - App Pool Timeout Change]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Tommy...thanks for the feedback.  Is there anyway to increase the 20 minute default?

Comment: @MikeTWebb - yup, I just threw in those links.  Seems to be some confusion of IIS 6 or 7 above, so both have been posted.

Comment: @Tommy....thanks!  Do you know if it's possible to run a util to auto run a web page?  Not sure if that's a good idea or not

Comment: You could - basically have a sort of 'heartbeat' service that pings your site on some interval or after publishing.  I can't really say if it is a good idea or not, just depends on how much traffic/load you have and the importance of the speedy response after a deployed update or app pool recycle.

Comment: @Tommy....how would such a heartbeat service engage the web app?  Performance is an issue for our app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226060/c-sharp-ping-a-website-keep-alive-service should do it..

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-compile your pages to speed up initial loading time.

See this MSDN section for more info:
[ASP.NET Web Site Precompilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015%28v=vs.85%29)

Messing with application timeout (by setting it to a very large value) may be contra-productive as it will disable automatic recycling of dormant applications.

Comment: @Marten....thanks.  That was helpful, too.  If I could accept both answers, I would.